# Multiple field result in select statement in SYBASE DB

Tags: sybase

I am trying to get a result like shown below in sybase db.

```
Select fruit = select names from Food where food_type = 'fruit', veg = select names from Food where food_type = 'veg', * from Food
```

And the result will be

```
ID  fruit  veg  
-- ------- ---- 
1   apple  onion 
    grapes chill
    orange carrot
```

how this is possible in sybase

Comment: where does the `ID` column come from? how did you decide to match `apple` with `onion` as opposed to `chill` or `carrot`? you're effectively running 2 different queries and then trying to join the results ... but what are you joining on?

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?

Answer (score 0):

In Sybase ASA and Sybase IQ, you can create that output as below:

```
SELECT TF.RowNum ID, TF.charcol1 fruit, TV.charcol1 vegetable
FROM 
  ( SELECT charcol1, ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER ( ORDER BY charcol1 ASC ) AS RowNum
    FROM fruit_table ) AS TF,
  ( SELECT charcol1, ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER ( ORDER BY charcol1 ASC ) AS RowNum
    FROM vegetable_table ) AS TV
WHERE TF.RowNum=TV.RowNum
ORDER BY TF.RowNum;
```

In Sybase ASE it's tad trickier:

```
select RowNum = identity(3), charcol1 
into #temp_table_F from fruit_table;

select RowNum = identity(3), charcol1 
into #temp_table_V from vegetable_table;

SELECT TF.RowNum ID, TF.charcol1 fruit, TV.charcol1 vegetable
FROM #temp_table_F TF, #temp_table_V TV
WHERE TF.RowNum=TV.RowNum
ORDER BY TF.RowNum;
```